# About (functions) tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

Excerpt for [functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) tag says at the moment:

> Elementary questions involving functions.

From this it is not entirely clear what kind of questions the tag is intended for. But I definitely think that some question tagged by this tag do not correspond to this description. Maybe expanding tag-excerpt/tag-wiki could help but I did not want to this without discussing the issue here first.

I'll post an answer about what I think was the intended use; please, if you think that I've forgotten some important things or if you have better suggestions, please post them as answers.

I propose that if we reach some consensus about when this tag should be used, we can edit tag-excerpt to reflect this. (In order to help users to use this tag correctly.)

Comment: I should mention that complete removal of this tag was discussed at meta before: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/715/should-we-have-a-functions-tag

Comment: Huh, so in the first few weeks, when there were 7 questions tagged functions, there were already no compelling reason to keep that tag. And somehow it is still alive? Amazing. I had assumed it was a holdover from the "olden" days. But it seems I am not quite correct.

Answer (score 4):

Tag [functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) is intended for elementary questions about functions, which include:

- definition and basic properties of functions (domain, codomain, inverse function, bijective/injective/surjective functions, image and preimage of a set, even/odd functions etc...)
- names and notations for various functions
- For questions about graphs of function, we have [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) tag. But this tag can be combined with [functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions).

Obviously, the questions in the above areas will probably have large intersection with [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory) and [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus); but not all questions tagged [functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) fall under these two tags.

For more specialized topic, such as continuity, limit, derivative, maxima and minima, functional equations... we have different, more appropriate tags.